How to keep SplashScreen showing until dataStore is loaded in jetpack compose?
I want to keep the SpalshScreen (SplashScreen Api) untill the dataStore is loaded. Once dataStore is loaded it should go to the main app content. Here is my Code that i've attempted but its not working as expected.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val dataStore = this.dataStore
            var isLoading by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            LaunchedEffect(dataStore) {
                dataStore.data.collect{
                    isLoading = true
                }
            }
            splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition{ isLoading }

            MyAppTheme{
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                ) {
                    MyApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my splash screen Theme :
<resources>
        <style name="Theme.Kanago.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
            <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
            <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_icon</item>
            <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
            <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Kanago</item>
        </style>
</resources>


You need to keep your login inside the ViewModel and when your data fetching completed just update MutableStateFlow variable based on which splash screen would disappear.

@ChiragThummar can you please provide code demo with soltiion including my code. That would be really helpfull :)

I'll provide you basic demo tomorrow.

You are initializing your isLoading variable to false. So your SplashScreen listening for condition
splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition{ isLoading }

will probably immediately be hidden, and I am not sure whether it will be shown again afterwards when you set isLoading to true.
So first, try to initialize isLoading to true and see if that already resolves your problem:
var isLoading by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

If not, you will need to redesign your logic to set isLoading to false when your data is ready, then the SplashScreen will be hidden.  I am sorry I can't help more in detail right now, as I don't quite understand what your code is doing.

Hi Benjy, hope you are doing well. What i'm trying to achieve with my code is that i have some values in DataStore the android API alternative to SharedPrefs. So i want that when the DataStore is instialized and ready to get the values from that then the splashscreen should hide and actual app will show otherwise the splash screen should remain there. Hope this carifies now. Please do let me know if i still didnt hit the point.
